# I want to sort data by distance but failed

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to sort data by distance but failed.

Table places

```
type Place struct 
{
    gorm.Model
    CountyName    string 
    Name          string  
    Address       string 
    ServiceTime   string 
    Phone         string  
    BusinessScope string  
    Remark        string 
    Lng           float64
    Lat           float64 
    Type          uint 
}
```

This works:

```
func PlaceList(placeType, fieldName, fieldValue string, pageNum, pageSize int) (places []Place, err error) {
    result := DB.Scopes(Paginate(pageNum, pageSize)).Scopes(Filter(placeType, fieldName, fieldValue)).Find(&places)
    return places, result.Error
}
```

I try to sort it , but that does not work:

```
func PlaceList(currentLng, currentLat, placeType, fieldName, fieldValue string, pageNum, pageSize int) (places []Place, err error) {
    var distance = "places.lng, places.lat, power((%s - places.lng),2) + power((%s - places.lat),2) as distance"
    var selectDistance  = fmt.Sprintf(distance, currentLng, currentLat)
    result := DB.Table("places").Select(selectDistance).Scopes(Paginate(pageNum, pageSize)).Scopes(Filter(placeType, fieldName, fieldValue)).Order("distance").Find(&places)
    return places, result.Error
}
```

Thanks to help me

Comment: Can you share what goes wrong, what error you get, what output you get on the debug log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now

```
func PlaceList(currentLng, currentLat, placeType, fieldName, fieldValue string, pageNum, pageSize int) (places []Place, err error) {
    var distance = "*, power((%s - places.lng),2) + power((%s - places.lat),2) as distance"
    var selectDistance = fmt.Sprintf(distance, currentLng, currentLat)
    result := DB.Debug().Table("places").Select(selectDistance).Scopes(Paginate(pageNum, pageSize)).Scopes(Filter(placeType, fieldName, fieldValue)).Order("distance").Find(&places)
    return places, result.Error
}
```